# Tight apartness relations in toposes

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory, constructive-mathematics

A [tight apartness relation](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/apartness+relation) on a set is a binary relation $\#$ such that the following conditions hold:

- $x = y$ if and only if $\neg (x \# y)$.
- If $x \# y$, then $y \# x$.
- If $x \# z$, then either $x \# y$ or $y \# z$ for every $y$.

I want to understand this notion better. Classically, it is completely trivial. Thus, it makes sense to look at it in various toposes. I tried to use the Kripke-Joyal semantics to get the external interpretation of an arbitrary object of a topos with a tight apartness relation, but it seems that it does not give anything particularly interesting in general. Thus, I've got the following question:

> **Question:** What are examples of objects in toposes with a tight apartness relation which externally correspond to some interesting or useful notion?

Since constructively, a set can have more than one tight apartness relation on it, I'd like to see examples of an object with two different tight apartness relations which both have interesting interpretations.

**Edit:** There are several "generic" examples of objects with tight apartness relations, i.e., objects that can be defined in every topos (e.g., Dedekind reals). I'm particularly interested in "non-generic" examples, i.e., objects that can be constructed only in a specific topos.

Comment: I'm a little out of my depth here, but I think the first bullet point tells you that in a topos, any object admitting an apartness relation must have decidable equality. I think the first two toposes I tend to think of besides $Set$ are $sSet$ and sheaves on a topological space $X$. In $sSet$, I think maybe only discrete objects have decidable equality? And in $Sh(X)$, maybe it's just coproducts of representables on clopen sets?

Comment: The relation with the [Hausdorff topology](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hausdorff+space#in_constructive_mathematics) may be helpful.

Comment: @TimCampion It does not imply decidability of equality, it only implies that it is $\neg \neg$-separated. There are plenty of examples of objects with an apartness relation and without decidable equality. E.g., functions $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ and Dedekind reals.

Comment: @ValeryIsaev: Can you clarify? The condition "$\forall x,y : M. \neg\neg(x = y) \Rightarrow x = y$", interpreted in the internal language, is exactly the condition for the object $M$ to be separated with respect to the $\neg\neg$-topology.

Comment: @ValeryIsaev Surely you're right. Just to clarify (since it's the "tight"-ness part that has me confused more so than the "apartness" part), you're saying that in a topos, $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ and $\mathbb R$ have _tight_ apartness relations, right? BTW is there a name for objects $X$ with $\neg\neg$-dense diagonal? I didn't realize there was a condition like this on the equality relation intermediate between decidability and non-decidability...

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt Yes, you're right. I just was confused. I deleted my comment.

Comment: @TimCampion Yes, they both carry a tight apartness relation. Also, my second comment was completely wrong. First, the condition "$\neg \neg x = y \implies x = y$" is equivalent to the diagonal being $\neg \neg$-closed and not $\neg \neg$-dense. Second, as Ingo pointed out, it is actually equivalent to the object being $\neg \neg$-separated.

Comment: @TimCampion I'm asking about _tight_ apartness relations because every apartness relation on $X$ determine a tight one on a quotient of $X$. For example, the relation "$(x - y)$ is a unit" on a local ring is an apartness relation. The corresponding ideal is (the unique) maximal ideal consisting of non-units, the quotient is a Heyting field, and the tight apartness relation on this field is the same as before. Thus, I believe that, to understand apartness relations, it is enough to understand tight ones.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not precisely sure what you're looking for. Here is an example for the external interpretation of an apartness relation:

Recall that the object of Dedekind reals $\mathbb{R}$ in a sheaf topos $\mathrm{Sh}(X)$ is the sheaf $\mathcal{C}$ of continuous (Dedekind-)real-valued functions on $X$.

The apartness relation on $\mathbb{R}$, defined by $x \mathrel{\#} y \Longleftrightarrow x - y \text{ is invertible}$, is then the following subsheaf $\mathcal{E}$ of $\mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C}$:

$$ \mathcal{E}(U) = \{ (f,g) \,|\, \text{for all $x \in U$: $f(x) - g(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ is invertible} \} $$

Comment: I'd like to see more examples like this one, but I think even more interesting are non-generic examples. That is, objects with tight apartness relations that can be constructed only in some particular topos (here, $\mathbb{R}$ can be constructed in any topos).

Comment: @ValeryIsaev I think it would be a good idea to include this requirement into your question.